# Trim whitespace from selection with Rangy

Tags: javascript, rangy

I'm using Rangy 1.2. Let's say the user selects the text " abcd". I am trying to trim the selection to just be "abcd".

I have already created a Rangy selection, and range on the selection. It seems like the function I want to use is setStartAfter(node) but it isn't returning anything for me.

I have been following these docs: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this is a little tricky because the space character may not be part of the same node as "abcd". Rangy 1.2 doesn't have any special methods to help you: the Range implementation is just the same as DOM Range, with a few extensions, so the problem is no different to what it would be without Rangy. If all of the text is within a single text node, say "123 abcd efg", and the user had selected " abcd", you'd need to do something like this, assuming you have a reference to the text node in a variable called `textNode` and the selection range in a variable called `range`:

```
range.setStart(textNode, 4);
rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
```

Rangy 1.3, however, has a [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) to deal with ranges and selections in terms of their text. With it, your problem could be solved with

```
rangy.getSelection().trim();
```

Demo:

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/timdown/rangy-release/master/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/timdown/rangy-release/master/rangy-textrange.js"></script>

<input type="button" onmousedown="rangy.getSelection().trim(); return false" value="Trim selection">
<div contentEditable="true">
  Please select something in here and press the button abcd efgh
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I'm now stuck on is how to specify the new range to just be "abcd" in our example. I need a way to specify a new range, that is a sub-range - the trimmed version of the original range.

Unfortunately upgrading to 1.3 is not an option for me.